# ASP.NET MVC app with forms authentication going to the login url gets me a 302 and then a 401

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a problem with my ASP.NET 4.5 app using MVC 5.1 and forms authentication.

This is how I configured forms authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" defaultUrl="~/Account/Login" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

This is my login action:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;

        return View();
    }
```

I run my application in iis express by going to this url:

```
http://mymachine:59006/Account/Login
```

I get redirected to:

```
http://mymachine:59006/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fLogin
```

When I debug my action method the cursor reaches it twice.

What I found happens in the background is that for this url `http://mymachine:59006/Account/Login` a 302 response is received then this url is called `http://mymachine:59006/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fLogin` and I get a 401.

If I remove form authentication from Web.config it works and I get 200 when I access `http://mymachine:59006/Account/Login`, but I need it for the rest of my website.

Can anyone provide me with a solution?

Update 1: Tried it with the local IIS as well. Same problem

Update 2:
My Web.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" *censored* />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
    <add key="email_smtp" value="*censored*" />
    <add key="email_box" value="*censored*" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/Login" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="Views/Account/Login">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" protection="None" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="43200" />
    </authentication>
    <httpRuntime />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.WebData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer></configuration>
```

Comment: Is "Anonymous Authentication" enabled in IIS?

Comment: @AndreiV I am using IIS Express, yes Anonymous Authentication is enabled in the project properties

Comment: what namespace authorize attribute ? System.Web.Mvc ?

Comment: @Mediator Yes, I even changed it to "[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller" to be sure. No luck :(

Comment: @Para Could you provide your project to us?

Comment: Can you share your complete web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the authorization method to all controllers you have and try to secure your application using a global filter.

```
RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
  filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
  filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

The OnAuthorization Method of the Authorize Attribute looks for an AllowAnonymous Attribute on the action or the controller and bypasses authorization if this is the case.

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
    if (!filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined
        (typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit) &&
      !filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined
        (typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)) {
          // Check for authorization
    }
    //more....
}
```

Comment: How exactly do I bypass authorization if I find the AllowAnonymouseAttribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the default redirection url from the web.config. So that is looks like:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Also, check if you are referencing WebMatrix in your project. It will influence the redirection behavior. It adds additional keys to control redirection:

```
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
```

and

```
<add key="LoginUrl" value="~/Account/Login" />
```

Comment: Tried all of this. It still behaves the same way. I am not referencing Web.Matrix anyway. I tried it anywaybecause I am desperate but no luck :(.

Answer (score 0):

I really frustrated about the same issue as this one.

Your log in application web.config must have the same

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
```

to your new develop application or vice versa